# How to halt the growth but leave the tree?

Tags: trees, roots, pond, weeping-willow

I have a twisted /contorted / japanese/ willow tree (it is I'd say about 20ft high at the moment )next to my small garden pond. My son planted it (from a cutting) over the resting place of a deceased pet 14 or so years ago. It has grown very fast has no main trunk but four main parts, predictably perhaps, growing outwards rather than straight up. It has now been pollarded back twice. I am now wondering as the garden is small whether I ought soon to think of cutting it down and somehow stopping the root growth (chemically?) but I would prefer to retain the body of the tree in order to; a) to install a platform- balcony affair where I can sit, and b) thus to provide some shade and cover for the pond and it's inhabitants. Is this even possible?

Comment: can you upload a picture or two to imgur.com so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: You want to kill the tree without removing the tree and the result would be a dead tree with no leaves standing next to the garden? I'm just trying to be clear on what is being asked.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold for now. If you add the photographs and the extra information that people asked for, please flag your question and ask for it to be re-opened.